# c++ polymorphism and non virtual functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a question:
How can I implement a non_virtual function in class that derived from abstract class? For example:

```
class A {
    public:
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A{
    public:
        virtual void foo() {
            /* some code */
        }
        //B function
        void Bfoo(){
            /* some code */
        }
};

int main(){
    A* a = new B;
    a -> foo();
    a -> Bfoo();
    return 0;
}
```

g++ gets:

```
error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘Bfoo’ 
a -> Bfoo();
```

Is there a way to use polymorphism and use non-virtual functions?

**EDIT**

I know that A hasn't got `Bfoo()` function so I get the error. I asked this question because I didn't understand when is useful use polymorphism.

My answer could be:

I use polymorphism when my derived classes have all the same function and derived from one common base class.

But if a class has an other function the polymorphism drops?

Comment: It's unclear what you expect to happen. `A` has no such method, it should be obvious why you're not able to call it from a pointer to `A`. This sounds like an XY problem, please describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `((B*)a) -> Bfoo()`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this fix works, but it forces too much the meaning of polymorphism. If I use `((B*)a) -> Bfoo()` I could use `B* a = new B` instead of `A* b = new B`

Comment: Well yes, but that's not the point. The point is that you have the ability to typecast class A to class B since it's derived. Otherwise, it makes no sense that you'd want to call a member function on an instance of a class that doesn't have it defined.

Comment: Yes, a class can add a function that is not in its base class. `class Airplane: public Vehicle { public: void takeOff(); void land(); };` Do you see any problem with this example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use function `Bfoo()` with pointer `a`, you have to add the function `Bfoo()` to `class A` as `virtual`.

I mean

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void Bfoo() {} //this line is necessary
};
```

---

**EDIT** (after question changed)

The knowledge of definitions is necessary. Here is the definition of Virtual Members from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com)

> **Virtual members**
>   A virtual member is a member function that can be redefined in a derived class, while preserving its calling properties through references. The syntax for a function to become virtual is to precede its declaration with the virtual keyword.

See the [resource](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) for definitions of *Polymorphism* and *Virtual Functions/Members*.

Comment: Hi, this solution can be right if I have just `class B` as derived class, but what about also having `class C : public A`? I should implement `Bfoo()` with empty `{}`, but the interface of my program is bad and not 
readable at all

Answer (score 0):

A derived class can have additional non-virtual functions, but they must be called **from a pointer or reference to the derived class**.

The point of polymorphism is for the calling code to not have to care about what concrete class the variable it's acting on is.

Usually such methods would be part of a class's private implementation, and not part of the public interface. Any non-virtual public facing methods in a derived class implicitly force the calling code to be aware of the concrete type of the class.

You could of course cast your `A*` to a `B*` but this kind of defeats the point of polymorphism. It's hard to give more specific advice without a concrete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  At the moment haven't got an example. The question rise when I try to resolve an exercise and I think about polymorphism. Maybe I have to study more this (important) argument and understand well the point of polymorphism.